# Tumblr Theme- Container Doesn't Stretch to Match Posts

Tags: themes, containers, tumblr

I'm not very good with HTML or anything like that so please bear with me! So I'm editing a tumblr theme (that someone else made, not me) and I moved the sidebars from the right to the left, which messed everything on the theme up. I've almost got it looking how I wanted layout wise, but the container won't stretch to match the posts or the page etc. You can see what I mean here (sorry can't post images):

vbthemes.tumblr.com/page

Even on the main page it isn't quite long enough to go down past the pagination.

Ideally I want the container to stretch down to the bottom of the posts/post on the page.

This is the code for the container:

> /*/ CONTAINER /*/
>
> ```
>  .containerbg{
> padding:20px;
> margin-left:-40px;
> margin-top:29px;
> background:{color:containerbg};
> padding-top:10px;
> width: 880px;
> height: 100%;
> z-index:-1000;
> }
> ```

Can anyone give me any tips?
I can provide more of the code if you need, as I said I'm a huge noob.

(the theme was made by themesofcaroline.tumblr.com and i take no credit for it)

Comment: What happens if you remove width:800px from the .containerbg class?

Comment: Scratch that, I may have a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble testing this, but this should work.

Add the following css to your theme:

```
/* -------------------------------
CLEARFIX FLOATING FIXES
---------------------------------- */
.clearfix:after { 
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
  .clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
.clear { overflow:hidden; clear:both; height:1px; margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:1px; }
.clear-simple {clear:both; }
```

Then add clearfix class to your container. So:

```
 <div class="containerbg clearfix">
```

Untested but try it.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, only it pushed all my posts down but i can easily fix that! The only thing it did was it made a funny little like "dent" in the container down the bottom of the main page and on the side of my pages! Do you have any suggestions for that? Thank you soooooo much though, I would never have been able to fix it!

Comment: Yeah I think it is because you have a div containerbg inside another div containerbg, and that class has padding 20px. I managed to fix it in the browser by taking padding:20px off the parent container. I think it would be best to remove the class. Or apply different properties to the parent.

Comment: And if my answer works for you, would you be kind enough to mark it as accepted please? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and see if that works once I get back onto tumblr next :) I've ticked the little green tick, if that's not what I'm supposed to do to accept it let me know and I will! Thanks again so much!!

Comment: Glad to be of service. :D